# Multiple Images in a Tkinter canvas

Tags: python, image, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I am having issue with this code. 
Actually,
1. Download the images using url
2. Save those images to in a server 
3. Display them in a canvas

The problem I am having is it's showing only the last image (in this case img2 from url2) from the list, not the first one, Even though I do see a blank space has been added in the Canvas for the first image.

Any one know what I am missing here. I appreciate your help.

Are there any other ways to get the images and showing in canvas, without saving them in to the local.

```
class open_child_window:
    def init(self, master):
        self.master = master
        master.title("Img")
```

url1 ="http:img1"
    url2 ="http:img2"


    vscrollbar = Tk.Scrollbar(self.master,orient=VERTICAL)
    hscrollbar=Tk.Scrollbar(self.master,orient=HORIZONTAL)

    self.canvas= Tk.Canvas(self.master,background = "White",yscrollcommand=vscrollbar.set,xscrollcommand=hscrollbar.set)
    self.frame = Tk.Frame(self.canvas)
    vscrollbar.config(command=self.canvas.yview)
    vscrollbar.pack(side=Tk.RIGHT, fill=Tk.Y)

    hscrollbar.pack(side=Tk.BOTTOM,fill=Tk.X)
    hscrollbar.config(command=self.canvas.xview)

    self.canvas.create_window(0,0,window=self.frame, anchor='nw')            

    self.list_images = []


    contents = urllib.request.urlopen(ur1l)

    plt.imshow(plt.imread(contents))
    file_name = "./img1.png"
    plt.savefig(file_name, format='png', dpi=180)

    gif1 = PhotoImage(file = file_name)
    self.canvas.image_names = gif1
    self.canvas.create_image(50, 10, image = gif1, anchor = NW)


    contents = urllib.request.urlopen(url2)

    plt.imshow(plt.imread(contents))
    file_name = "./img2.png"
    plt.savefig(file_name, format='png', dpi=180)

    gif2 = PhotoImage(file = file_name)
    self.canvas.image_names = gif2
    self.canvas.create_image(600, 700, image = gif2, anchor = NW)


    self.master.update()  
    self.canvas.config(scrollregion=self.canvas.bbox("all"))
    self.canvas.pack(side="top",fill='both',expand=True)
    self.frame.pack()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve with my issue.

in case if some one else looking for the solution.

Have added self in front of gif1 and gif2 like self.gif1 and self.gif2.